# IIR coefficients that simply boost the signal

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

Is there a way to get IIR coefficients that only amplify a signal, nothing more? I suppose some phase shifting would be ok as well as long as it's not too noticeable.

Background: I am using a MiniDSP board and I'm attempting to use the filter section as a level booster to drive the sound into a compressor downstream. The MiniDSP allows you to type in whatever filter coefficients you want in the EQ section.

Comment: Set b0 to whatever gain you want. Set b1, b2, a1, a2 to 0.

Comment: @Ben that should be an answer. Also please point out that scaling the coefficients of any other, already used, filter would do, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that your IIR filter is an order-2 biquad. But the reasoning remains the same if the implementation is different.

Original filter : $H(z) = \frac{b_0+b_1\cdot z^{-1}+b\cdot z^{-2}}{1 + a_1\cdot z^{-1} + a_2\cdot z^{-2}}$

If you want to boost your signal by G

$H_G(z) = G\frac{b_0+b_1\cdot z^{-1}+b_2\cdot z^{-2}}{1 + a_1\cdot z^{-1} + a_2\cdot z^{-2}}$

simply distribute G to the numerator

$H_G(z) = \frac{G\cdot b_0+G\cdot b_1\cdot z^{-1}+G\cdot b_2\cdot z^{-2}}{1 + a_1\cdot z^{-1} + a_2\cdot z^{-2}}$

Simply multiply your b0-b2 coefficients by G.

In the case where you simply want to boost the signal without filering it at all. Set $b_0$ to $G$, $b_1$, $b_2$ to $0$, as well as  $a_1$ and $a_2$ to 0.

Comment: upvoted (replaced all the $*$ with $\cdot$ to avoid confusion with convolution). Nice work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
% Octave packages -------------------------------
pkg load signal

GdB = 6.0; % gain in dB
gain = 10^(GdB/20); % convert

a = 1;
b = gain;

CB = tf(b, a, 1);

figure(1);

bode(CB,'b');
grid on;
```

[image]

If you need to use biquad type filter then just set those other coefficients to 0. 
Example: b 0 0 1 0 0 (IIRC, MiniDSP had some other ordering ...?).